# Define a Style color with a PHP variable?

Tags: php, html, colors, styles

How can I define a style color with a php variable ?
I've tried this:

```
 <div id ="centro" style="color:<?php $_SESSION['colore'];?>">
```

Any help would be a appreciated.

Comment: echo it and make sure you've started the session. *Why is this code not working?*

Comment: @Asis <div id ="centro" style="color:<?php echo $_SESSION['colore']?>">  </div>

Comment: Hi! I can't Vote up because of my reputation,I need 15 reputation to accept the answers. I admire the job of those who answer and dedicate their time to help other people. I really appreciate their job.Thanks to everyone and sorry for my broken English.regards.

Comment: Ok! I see that! Thanks Fred -ii-.

Comment: You're welcome. Please visit all your other questions you posted and do the same for the ones who gave you a solution. I am sure they will appreciate it very much, *cheers*. Plus, you get additional rep points when you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<div id ="centro" style="color:<?php echo $_SESSION['colore']?>"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `echo`:

```
<div id="centro" style="color:<?php echo $_SESSION['colore']; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to echoing the variable. like this:

```
<div id ="centro" style="color:<?php echo $_SESSION['colore'] ?>">  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<?php echo $_SESSION<['colore'];?>` instead of `<?php $_SESSION['colore'];?>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id ="centro" style="color:<?php echo $_SESSION['color'];?>">
```

but color should be be previously set in session

Answer (score 0):

better solution. don't use long tags for short things

```
<?=$_SESSION['colore']?>
```

above does not need `echo`

Comment: Only if short tags are enabled. In older versions of PHP, short tags were disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use shorthand instead which is a little less to write:

```
<?=$_SESSION['colore'];?>
```